# How can I render what a SCNCamera sees onto a plane?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I would like to get the camera data from an `SCNCamera` and render what the camera sees in the virtual 3D environment as a material onto a plane like a security camera in a game. Is there any way to do this in `SceneKit` or is this out of the scope of what `SceneKit` has to offer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SK3DNode in SpriteKit can achieve this for you.

The documentation has a good explanation about this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sk3dnode.

All you have to do in addition to this is to use the SKTexture as the content of diffuse property for the material of the plane you want to render to.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it's just a case of creating the camera, creating the node you want to display the output and then using...

```
node.camera = theCamera
```

Does that not work?

You can read more about `SCNNode` and the `camera` property in the [Apple, SCNNode docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407976-camera).